# i need to get multiple query values to a one data set

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable, audit

i want to create a report from an audit table [this is the audit table, i need to get the count of address, tele, and AssName(AssociationName) of each and every person specificly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nive.png)

```
 select count(tele),count(AssName),count(Address) from Audit where name='ben'   
 select count(tele),count(AssName),count(Address) from Audit where name='nik'
 select count(tele),count(AssName),count(Address) from Audit where name='josh'
```

this is the query i used but i need these  individual tables into one table and the count should be calculated if only "1" is in these cells. but my table has "0"s but it consider them as values and counts "0" cells too[this is the tabel now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnE84.png)

Comment: Would a "Union All" work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT 
 name,
 sum(case when tele is not null then 1 else 0 end) tele,
 sum(case when Assname is not null then 1 else 0 end) Assname,
 sum(case when Address is not null then 1 else 0 end) Address
 FROM Audit
 GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

try a group by instead

```
 SELECT 
  name,
  count(tele),
  count(AssName),
  count(Address) 
  FROM Audit 
    GROUP BY name
```

Comment: ok this works. but i need to get the count of the colomns tele,AssName,Address which has 1 in these colomns. if not then(if null) it should not be included to count

Answer (score 0):

```
Select name , count (Assname), count (Address), count(tele)
from Audit
GROUP by Name
```

This would return your desired result.

Edit: I misunderstood your question earlier. You need to add group by the name if you want to count the number of each name a person is in the table.

Comment: i don't think so. You missed a `GROUP BY` and also that will not give any result :)

Answer (score -1):

just use GROUP BY

```
select name, count(tele),count(AssName),count(Address) from Audit group by name
```

Comment: ok this works. but i need to get the count of the colomns tele,AssName,Address which has 1 in these colomns. if not then(if null) it should not be included to count